# data from from plist did not load

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Can anyone help me to solve the problem. I would like to develop my app using property list with nsobject. When run the app, there is no error but the data from bnm.plist did not load on uitableview.

Below is ViewController.m

```
#import "MCWViewController.h"
#import "MCWPlacesDetailViewController.h"
#import "MCWPlaces.h"

@interface MCWViewController ()

@end

@implementation MCWViewController {
    NSArray *places;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data

    // Find out the path of bnm.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bnm" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    MCWPlaces *placeGO = [MCWPlaces new];
    placeGO.name = [dict objectForKey:@"PlaceName"];
    placeGO.info = [dict objectForKey:@"PlaceInfo"];

    places = [NSArray arrayWithObject:placeGO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [places count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PlacesCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"PlacesCell");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    MCWPlaces *place = [places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = place.name;
    return cell;


}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPlaceDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MCWPlacesDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.place = [places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Below is Places.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MCWPlaces : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *info;

@end
```

Below is Places.m

```
#import "MCWPlaces.h"

@implementation MCWPlaces

@synthesize name;
@synthesize info;


@end
```

Below is Details.m

```
#import "MCWPlacesDetailViewController.h"


@interface MCWPlacesDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation MCWPlacesDetailViewController 

@synthesize placeInfo;
@synthesize place;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = place.name;
    self.placeInfo.text = place.info;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Below is Details.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MCWPlaces.h"

@interface MCWPlacesDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *placeInfo;

@property (nonatomic, strong) MCWPlaces *place;



@end
```

bnm.plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PlaceName</key>
    <array>
        <string>Place 1</string>
        <string>Place 2</string>
        <string>Place 3</string>
    </array>
    <key>PlaceInfo</key>
    <array>
        <string>Place 1 Info</string>
        <string>Place 2 Info</string>
        <string>Place 3 Info</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Did something wrong in my code?

I think my problem is 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and i have declared 'name' and 'info' as nsstring on Places.h. but on plist is as nsarray. but i dont know how to solve the problem.

Comment: where is the file? in the _bundle_ or in the `Documents` folder? because it is in the `Documents` folder, the method `–pathForResource:ofType:` won't provide the path for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you are in the wrong way.
Use the following code and replace it in your project :

**bnm.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PlaceName</key>
        <string>Place 1</string>
        <key>PlaceInfo</key>
        <string>Place 1 Info</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>PlaceName</key>
        <string>Place 2</string>
        <key>PlaceInfo</key>
        <string>Place 2 Info</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

**MCWPlaces.h**

```
@interface MCWPlaces : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *info;

@end
```

**MCWPlaces.m**

```
#import "MCWPlaces.h"

@implementation MCWPlaces

@synthesize name;
@synthesize info;

@end
```

**MCWViewController.m**

```
#import "MCWViewController.h"
#import "MCWPlaces.h"

#define KEY_PLACE_NAME  @"PlaceName"
#define KEY_PLACE_INFO  @"PlaceInfo"

@interface MCWViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *places;

@end


@implementation MCWViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Init place array
    _places = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Find out the path of bnm.plist
    NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bnm" ofType:@"plist"]];

    NSLog(@"%@", data);

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < data.count; i++)
    {
        MCWPlaces *placeGO = [MCWPlaces new];

        placeGO.name = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_PLACE_NAME];
        placeGO.info = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:KEY_PLACE_INFO];

        [_places addObject:placeGO];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", _places);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _places.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PlacesCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"PlacesCell");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }



    NSLog(@"%@", [_places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [[_places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    return cell;


}

@end
```

Comment: it's work..thank you very much..from your code, i added '- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender' to load PlaceInfo

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem when you load your data.

Firstly you say you get data from place.plist but in your viewDidLoad you tried to load data from bnm.plist

Try to use the following code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data

    // Find out the path of bnm.plist
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bnm" ofType:@"plist"]];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    MCWPlaces *placeGO = [MCWPlaces new];
    placeGO.name = [dict objectForKey:@"PlaceName"];
    placeGO.info = [dict objectForKey:@"PlaceInfo"];
}
```

Could you show us your bnm.plist ?

Comment: @jordon, sorry, actually the plist file is bnm.plist an i have inserted the plist. When i put "places = [NSArray arrayWithObject:placeGO];" and when run the app the is output '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75992e0' and the app will break at 'cell.textLabel.text = place.name;'

Comment: @jordon, i've try your suggested code but it is same. i think my problem is 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and i have declared 'name' and 'info' as nsstring on Places.h. but on plist is as nsarray. but i dont know how to solve the problem..

Comment: please share your the construction of your plist file.

Comment: @shhrzl try my second answer ;)